# Redirection of a webpage from one domain to another domain

Tags: php, redirect

How to redirect a user from one domain to another after he has **logged in** ?

Using **PHP**

Comment: One thing to note: If your login process involves cookies, they will not carry over to another domain. Ex. Cookies set on example.com cannot be accessed from other.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are runnig Apache this could be done through a `.htaccess` file, you could also send the user to a specific page when he/she logges in and at the top of that file use:

```
 header('Location: http://your-redirection-uri.com';
 exit();
```

Comment: How could i done the redirection through .htaccess file??Please describe

Comment: You could append something like ?logged_in=1 to the url and catch this argument in your `.htaccess` file

Comment: @KristerAndersson This could be exploited if you didn't authenticate on your second domain because anyone could append ?logged_in=1 to their url without actually having logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Use [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
header('Location:http://www.xyz.com/abc.php');
```

`xyz.com` is new domain

write some session start code on `abc.php` file
and then redirect a page where u actually want to redirect

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
header("Location: http://www.somedomain.com");
```

Hope it helps